# Trouble mapping array javascript

Tags: javascript, polymer, lit-html

So I'm trying to build a chart as a webcomponent and I'm having some trouble with mapping an array. The error says: this.values.map is not a function

Here is the code:

```
import {LitElement, html, css} from 'lit-element';


class ApexChart extends LitElement {

static get properties(){
    return{
        values: {Array},
        labels: {Array}
    };
}

constructor(){
    super();
    this.values = [];
    this.labels =[];
}

static get styles(){
    return css `

    `;
}

render(){
    return html`
         <p>${this.values.map(value => {value + 1})}</p>
    `;
}


}

customElements.define('apex-chart', ApexChart);
```

I'm passing the values from html

```
<apex-chart values="[1,2,3,4]" labels="['Hi', 'Hello', 'Oi', 'Hola']"></apex-chart>
```

I can't see what I'm doing wrong

Comment: I haven't used Polymer, but should you just be accessing `values` instead of `this.values`?

Comment: The `map` syntax is wrong: It should either be `this.values.map(value => value + 1)` or `this.values.map(value => { return value + 1 })`

Comment: Changed it but the error persists

Comment: if I change to values insted of this.values says that values is not defined

Comment: You can add a `console.log(this.values)` just before `return html` and check the values. Also, does `this` inside `render` refer to the instance of `ApexChart`.

Comment: I did this befero with this.values and values are correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two issues:

1) the `properties` [type converter](https://lit-element.polymer-project.org/guide/properties#conversion-type) is not defined correctly. It should be:

```
static get properties(){
    return{
        values: { type: Array },
        labels: { type: Array }
    };
}
```

2) The map method isn't working correctly. Currently it returns `undefined` values because if you use `{}` you must use the `return` keyword.

```
> [0, 1].map(value => { value + 1 })
<- (2) [undefined, undefined]
```

Instead use:

```
render(){
    return html`
         <p>${this.values.map(value => value + 1)}</p>
    `;
}
```

Or:

```
render(){
    return html`
         <p>${this.values.map(value => { return value + 1; })}</p>
    `;
}
```

Comment: After spending some time testing the code I found the problem. It seems that I can't pass an array that way, because is understood as a String. But if I pass the way below, it understands correct as an array of objects. Any thoughts on this?  Thank you so much
`<apex-chart values='[["Hi", 1], ["Hello", 2], ["Oi", 3], ["Hola", 4]]'></apex-chart>`

Comment: `values="[1]"` and `values='[["Hi", 1]]"` are both arrays and will be deserialized the same way. They will just have different values.